# Webscraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape [this web page](https://www.education.com/magazine/article/Ed_50_Words_SAT_Loves_2/) with R and rvest. I want to extract the fifty words in this format:

[image]

So far I have been able to do this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
words<-read_html("https://www.education.com/magazine/article/Ed_50_Words_SAT_Loves_2/")
just_words<-words %>% html_nodes("ol") %>% html_text()
strsplit(just_words,"\r\n\t")
```

I am able to reach up to this output only, with all 50 words:

[image]

Any help?

**EDIT**

I am well aware of the [Terms of Use of the website](https://www.education.com/terms-of-use/?cid=11.2194). This question is solely for practice purposes to improve scraping skills.

Comment: _…"you may not modify, edit, copy, reproduce, redistribute, create derivative works of, reverse engineer, alter, enhance or in any way exploit any of this website…"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted just_words list into dataframe and then used `separate` in `tidyr` package to split the column.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
words<-read_html("https://www.education.com/magazine/article/Ed_50_Words_SAT_Loves_2/")
just_words<-words %>% html_nodes("ol") %>% html_text()
x <- as.data.frame(strsplit(just_words,"\r\n\t"), col.names = "V1")
head(x)
t <- x %>% separate(V1, c("Word", "Meaning"), extra = "merge", fill = "left")
head(t)
```

Output:

```
> head(t)
        Word                                             Meaning
1   abstract                                        not concrete
2  aesthetic        having to do with the appreciation of beauty
3  alleviate                          to ease a pain or a burden
4 ambivalent simultaneously feeling opposing feelings; uncertain
5  apathetic                   feeling or showing little emotion
6 auspicious                                favorable; promising
```

If you are looking for a more formatted output, use pander package. The output displays as below:

```
> library(pander)
> pander(head(t))

---------------------------------------
   Word              Meaning           
---------- ----------------------------
 abstract          not concrete        

aesthetic     having to do with the    
              appreciation of beauty   

alleviate   to ease a pain or a burden 

ambivalent    simultaneously feeling   
           opposing feelings; uncertain

apathetic   feeling or showing little  
                     emotion           

auspicious     favorable; promising    
---------------------------------------
```

To remove line breaks and spaces.

```
t <- t %>% mutate(Meaning=gsub("[\r\n]", "", Meaning)) %>% tail()
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, it's working good. Now the issue is that the last word looks like this: `50    vindicated    freed from blame\r\n`. How to remove `\r\n` of the last word programmatically?

Comment: @Suman edited the answer. gsub can be used to replace line breaks. Please mark this as answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the details of the webpage (right-click and Inspect in Chrome), you will see that the word is provided in bold (wrapped in `strong` child tag under the same `li` node). Therefore it should be possible to fetch the two items separately.

```
library(rvest)
words <-read_html("https://www.education.com/magazine/article/Ed_50_Words_SAT_Loves_2/") %>% 
  html_nodes("#article-detail3 li")

data.frame( words = words %>% html_node("strong") %>% html_text(),
            meaning = words %>% html_node(xpath="./text()") %>% html_text())
```

The `xpath=./text()` specifies that you want only text of parent, but not children nodes.